# google api python client for existing access token

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

I use django allauth for logging using google, facebook.

So, I have access token from google(with all necessary scopes/permissions).

I want to use google api python client with this access token. But most of the examples in google website shows using client secret.

For example, I run cron jobs. For which I need to use an existing token, not client secret etc.

Please let me know solution for this.

Thanks.

Comment: I am also facing the similar issue. Have you been able to find a good solution?